# Is it possible to use makeForkCluster to create R processes in different machines?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

> "makeForkCluster uses the OS level fork call to create multiple
>   identical R processes on the same machine with a copy of the master
>   workspace"

but ...

*Is it possible to use makeForkCluster to create R processes in different machines?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is the way it says in the help page you quoted. The process produced by [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) necessarily runs on the same computer. You can use `makePSOCKcluster(names, ...)` where `names` is a character vector of machine names to create a cluster with R processes on  different machines.

Comment: Where is that quote from? It's _not_ from `?parallel::makeForkCluster`. (Not saying it's wrong, but it's useful to know the source to understand where you're coming from and the intent of the question).  If your question is really "Can I parallelize across machines" rather than "can I parallelize across machines *using forked processes*", then the answer is yes (as Ralf Stubner shows)

Comment: @HenrikB Interesting question. I had thought it came from the help page without checking it. This [presentation](http://www.bytemining.com/files/talks/larug/hpc2012/HPC_in_R_rev2012.pdf#page=20)  seems to be the actual source. Not as authoritative, but still correct.